# block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :order (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running rails 4.1.0.rc2 and I'm getting the ArgumentError `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :order` when I try to do:

```
has_many :workout_exercises, dependent: :destroy, order: "exercise_order DESC"`
```

I want to put an order constraint on my join model, and as far as I can tell, this worked with Rails 3.2, so I can't figure out what is going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
has_many :workout_exercises, dependent: :destroy,-> { order "exercise_order desc" }
```

**Update**, as per OP's comment (reorder the directives):

```
has_many :workout_exercises,-> { order "exercise_order desc" }, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Awesome, that works as long as I do the order `has_many :workout_exercises,-> { order "exercise_order desc" }, dependent: :destroy`. Can you explain the difference between using `order:' and `-> {order ""}`?

Comment: No difference, but in latter versions of rails you can't use activerecord methods outside a scope block in associations. Check this url and the examples http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Answer (score 2):

Giving another example that may help those who find this post.

```
# Rails 3 Syntax (below)
has_one :ca, :class_name => 'C::A',
        :foreign_key => 'person_id',
        :conditions => ['appl_id = ? AND status = ?', 4, 'active']
# Rails 4 Syntax (below) which replaces Rails 3 Syntax (above)
has_one(:ca, -> {where app_id: '4', status: 'active'}, class_name: 'C::A', foreign_key: 'person_id')
```